# query is returning " single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: sql

I am not sure why the below query is giving the " single-row subquery returns more than one row" please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
CASE
  WHEN s.servprov_gid = 'IFFCO.CAR-60041'
  THEN
    (SELECT E.EQUIPMENT_NUMBER
    FROM S_EQUIPMENT SE,
      EQUIPMENT E,
      SHIPMENT_S_EQUIPMENT_JOIN SSEJ,
      SHIPMENT S
    WHERE SSEJ.SHIPMENT_GID = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171203007'
    AND SE.S_EQUIPMENT_GID  = SSEJ.S_EQUIPMENT_GID
    AND E.EQUIPMENT_GID     = SE.EQUIPMENT_GID
    AND SSEJ.SHIPMENT_GID   = S.SHIPMENT_GID
    )
  ELSE
    (SELECT MIN(se.equipment_number)
    FROM shipment_s_equipment_join ssej,
      s_equipment se
    WHERE ssej.shipment_gid  = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171203007'
    AND ssej.s_equipment_gid = se.s_equipment_gid
    AND se.equipment_number IS NOT NULL
    )
END
```

Comment: Your `THEN` subquery doesn't use any form of aggregate (like the `MIN` in your `ELSE` clause subquery) so could easily return multiple rows. Exactly what the error message told you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message advise very clearly, more than one row are returned from the sub-query after the key word "Then". You can add "Top 1" after the first SELECT keyword for SQL Serve4. 
Or get the sub query end with "and rownum =1" for Oracle. The following is for SQL Server.

```
CASE
  WHEN s.servprov_gid = 'IFFCO.CAR-60041'
  THEN
    (SELECT TOP 1 E.EQUIPMENT_NUMBER
    FROM S_EQUIPMENT SE,
      EQUIPMENT E,
      SHIPMENT_S_EQUIPMENT_JOIN SSEJ,
      SHIPMENT S
    WHERE SSEJ.SHIPMENT_GID = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171203007'
    AND SE.S_EQUIPMENT_GID  = SSEJ.S_EQUIPMENT_GID
    AND E.EQUIPMENT_GID     = SE.EQUIPMENT_GID
    AND SSEJ.SHIPMENT_GID   = S.SHIPMENT_GID
    )
  ELSE
    (SELECT MIN(se.equipment_number)
    FROM shipment_s_equipment_join ssej,
      s_equipment se
    WHERE ssej.shipment_gid  = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.L171203007'
    AND ssej.s_equipment_gid = se.s_equipment_gid
    AND se.equipment_number IS NOT NULL
    )
END
```

Comment: When I am adding rownum=1 then I start getting "ORA-01008: not all variables bound"

Comment: @ShashankMishra I believe the part of statement would not throw the error you mentioned. Would you please share the whole SQL statement?